# Calculations with analog readings coming out wrong

Tags: c++, arduino

I am programming an Arduino Uno, and I'm getting stuck in a while loop because I am having trouble running a calculation on some sensor values. When I read my four sensors values and compare the ratio of the first two to the second two, I keep getting 0.00, no matter what the values are. Here's my code:

```
while ( ( (frontleft + frontright) / (backleft + backright) <= 0.8 ) || ( (frontleft + frontright) / (backleft + backright) > 1.2) ) {
    if (backleft + backright > frontleft + frontright) {
      myStepper2.step(10);
    }
    if (backleft + backright < frontleft + frontright) {
      myStepper2.step(-10);
    }
    int backleft = analogRead(A0);
    int backright = analogRead(A1);
    int frontleft = analogRead(A2);
    int frontright = analogRead(A3);   

    Serial.print("Backleft Reading: ");
    Serial.println(backleft);
    Serial.print("\n");
    Serial.print("BackRight Reading: ");
    Serial.println(backright);
    Serial.print("\n");
    Serial.print("Frontleft Reading: ");
    Serial.println(frontleft);
    Serial.print("\n");
    Serial.print("Frontright Reading: ");
    Serial.println(frontright);
    Serial.print("\n");
    float ratio = (frontleft + frontright) / (backleft + backright);
    float math = (5 + 6) / (4 + 5);
    Serial.print("Math: ");
    Serial.println(math);
    Serial.print("Ratio: ");
    Serial.println(ratio);
    Serial.print("\n");
    delay(500);

  }
```

I'm getting values for my sensors `backleft`, `backright`, `frontleft`, and `frontright` but 'ratio' always comes out 0.00. Because of that, I believe I'm getting trapped in the loop. What's going on here?

Also, just to check, I added 'math' float as that quick calculation, but I'm getting a value of 1.00 in Serial Monitor. Why? It should be 1.222.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
float ratio = (frontleft + frontright) / float((backleft + backright));
while ( ratio <= 0.8  ||  ratio > 1.2)  {
    //do your thing here

    ratio = (frontleft + frontright) / float((backleft + backright));
}
```

Then when you're trying to print

```
Serial.println(ratio, 4) //prints four decimal places
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it looks like it worked. But it's still stuck in the while loop, so it looks like I'll have to change that as well. It should exit the loop when the ratio is between 0.8 and 1.2. But that shouldnt be hard to do.

Comment: Even if this is the right solution, I suggest @crushendo to start thinking in integral math instead of using floats. It's really easy to use integers instead of floats in such cases (e.g. `10 * (frontleft + frontright) / (backleft + backright));`, or better `(10 * (frontleft + frontright) + 5) / (backleft + backright));` and then check with 8 and 12 instead of 0.8 and 1.2). After all, the microcontrollers DO NOT have floating point units, so why do you want to make your code bigger and slower?